# Missing ""AssignmentOperator Expression" in abstract class?

Tags: java, assignment-operator

For the following code:

```
private double currentTime;
private Queue<ScheduledEvent<S>> diary;

public Simulation() {
    diary = new PriorityQueue<ScheduledEvent<S>>;
}
```

within an abstract class called `Simulation<S>` I'm getting all of the following Eclipse errors.

- `Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens`
- `Syntax error, insert ">>" to complete ReferenceType2`
- `Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment`
- `Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements`

What is the cause? I don't see any typos or empty assignments that could cause this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're missing `()`

```
diary = new PriorityQueue<ScheduledEvent<S>>();
```

You're calling the constructor, and even when not passing any arguments that still requires `()`